# Extracting text between two keywords or a keyword and \n

Tags: regex

I have a set of lines where most of them follow this format

```
STARTKEYWORD some text I want to extract ENDKEYWORD\n
```

I want to find these lines and extract information from them.

Note, that the text between keywords can contain a wide range of characters (latin and non-latin letters, numbers, spaces, special characters) except `\n`.

**`ENDKEYWORD` is optional and sometimes can be omitted**.

My attempts are revolving around this regex

```
STARTKEYWORD (.+)(?:\n| ENDKEYWORD)
```

However capturing group `(.+)` consumes as many characters as possible and takes `ENDKEYWORD` which I do not need.

Is there a way to get `some text I want to extract` solely with regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make (.+) non greedy (which is by default greedy and eats whatever comes in its way) by adding `?` and add `$` instead of `\n` for making more efficient

```
STARTKEYWORD (.+?)(?:$| ENDKEYWORD$)
```

If you specifically want `\n` you can use:

```
STARTKEYWORD (.+?)(?:\n| ENDKEYWORD\n)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rI5nF1/5)

Comment: you could use `STARTKEYWORD (.+?)(?: ENDKEYWORD)?$` also.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookahead based regex. It always better to use `$` end of the line anchor since the last line won't contain a newline character at the last.

```
STARTKEYWORD (.+?)(?= ENDKEYWORD|$)
```

OR

```
STARTKEYWORD (.+?)(?: ENDKEYWORD|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rI5nF1/3)

Comment: Gives false positives for `STARTKEYWORD some text I want to extract ENDKEYWORDlalala

Comment: Where? it works https://regex101.com/r/rI5nF1/6 . OP wants to extract text upto `ENDKEYWORD` only if there contains ENDKEYWORD string else he wants to capture the whole line.

Comment: "false positives"... it matched for other than just ENDKEYWORD... :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj while it is not possible to get such string in my current setup but it would be great to process them as well.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I mean It would be great if regex matches all text betwen `STARTKEYWORD` and `ENDKEYWORD\n` or `\n`

Comment: @AvinashRaj sorry if it was unclear from the beginning. I upvoted your answer. Thanks for helping