# Changing text between possible keywords in bash script using sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

My `input` file has some text that needs to be changed. It has a couple of possibilities for example;

```
CONSTANT change/me !KEY2 !KEY3
CONSTANT change/me 
CONSTANT change/me !DIFFERENTKEY
```

There is always a constant key (i.e. `CONSTANT`) that doesn't change. There is also the possibilities of different keywords after the text that needs to be replaced. These are indicated with an exclamation mark (`!`) and there may be no other keywords or thousands. I am only interested in replacing the text after `CONSTANT` and any possible keys starting with `!`. Preferably using `sed`.

The following is my expected output. `change/me` in `input` has to be replaced with `changed`;

```
CONSTANT changed !KEY2 !KEY3
CONSTANT changed 
CONSTANT changed !DIFFERENTKEY
```

I have tried different things found in answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777579/how-to-output-only-captured-groups-with-sed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613643/replace-a-unknown-string-between-two-known-strings-with-sed), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074450/sed-replace-part-of-a-line?noredirect=1&lq=1)) on SO but I can't seem to figure it out. This closest I came was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867954/4524755) link.

`sed -r 's/(^CONSTANT) (.+?) (\!.*$)/\1 changed \3/g' input`

Which results in;

```
CONSTANT changed !KEY2
CONSTANT change/me
CONSTANT changed !DIFFERENTKEY
```

I tried different combinations but at this point it feels like I just shooting in the dark.

**Conditions:**

- `CONSTANT` doesn't change
- `change/me` is arbitrary text could also be
  `blahblah` that needs to be replaced
- A `!KEY` doesn't have to be
  present
- A `!KEY` can be present and can be multiple of them, but
  always separated with space. I want to maintain `CONSTANT` and any
  possible `!KEY`s.

Comment: Please do mention the conditions by which we should get this output in your post too.

Comment: If `'s/\/me//'` isn't all you need then clarify your requirements and provide better sample input/output that covers your actual needs.

Comment: What do you mean? `sed` would be useful

Comment: I am confused as how to make it more clear. Fine I will give it a think and delete for now...

Comment: @tstev, telling us the conditions by which you are getting output should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother handling the full line, whether additional content appears after the text to change doesn't matter :

```
sed 's@^CONSTANT change/me@CONSTANT changed@'
```

I used `@` as a separator instead of the usual `/` in order to avoid having to escape the `/` in `change/me`.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/b82YQB).

If the `change/me` text varies but never contains spaces, you can use the following instead :

```
sed -E 's@^CONSTANT [^ ]+@CONSTANT changed@'
```

(for older versions of GNU sed you will want to use the `-r` flag instead of `-E`)

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/o1r5Nt).

Comment: `change/me` was just a random text. it could also have been `pleasechange` or `blahblah`.

Comment: @tstev Yeah, I ended up getting this ; what about the second solution that will replace the sequence of non-space characters that follows `CONSTANT`?

Comment: This seems to work and I maintain my `!KEY` s. Thanks!

Comment: The `@` tip is also useful just incase i need to change it to a different absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

The third `(\!*.*$)` is forced to start with `!`, and the line 2 does not match.

Note that `(.+?) (\! ...` makes `sed` search for the longest sequence for `(.+?)` up to a `!...`, that is why `!KEY2` is lost.

Mandatory: the `change/me` never contains `!`, for the solution below to work.

Give a try to this:

```
sed -r 's/(^CONSTANT) ([^!]+?) *(\!.*|.*)$/\1 changed \3/g' input
```

**Output**

```
CONSTANT changed !KEY2 !KEY3
CONSTANT changed 
CONSTANT changed !DIFFERENTKEY
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. At least now I don't lose `!KEY2`. But it doesn't work for the second line. It remains `CONSTANT change/me`

Comment: @tstev I just updated the answer, and it worked in my test. Maybe you could refresh and see

Comment: Awesome, works too! Thank you very much for the explanation too.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but this adds a trailing space to lines without keys